# How to batch select data from Cassandra effectively?

Tags: cassandra, cql

I know Cassandra doesn't support batch query, and it also doesn't recommend to use `IN`, because it can degrade performance. But I have to get the data by id, for example:

```
select * from visit where id in ([visit_id array])
```

desc table:

```
CREATE TABLE visit (
    enterprise_id int,
    id text,
    ........
    PRIMARY KEY (enterprise_id, id)
```

The array maybe has thousands of elements. Is there any way can make it effectively?

Comment: Show us your table schema

Comment: @AshrafulIslam please look my update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Large In query create GC pauses and heap pressure that leads to overall slower performance. When you execute large in query this means you’re waiting on this single coordinator node to give you a response, it’s keeping all those queries and their responses in the heap, and if one of those queries fails, or the coordinator fails, you have to retry the whole thing.

Approach 1 :

Try to convert your in query into range query (>=, <=)

```
SELECT * visit WHERE enterprise_id = ? and id >= ? and id <= ?
```

Approach 2 :

Use executeAsync, Java Example

```
PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare("SELECT * FROM visit where enterprise_id = ? and id = ?");

List<ResultSetFuture> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    ResultSetFuture resultSetFuture = session.executeAsync(statement.bind(i, i));
    futures.add(resultSetFuture);
}

List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (ResultSetFuture future : futures){
     ResultSet rows = future.getUninterruptibly();
     Row row = rows.one();
     results.add(row.getString("name"));
}
return results;
```

Approach 3 :

If possible then instead of in query, create another table and when a data that you will perform in query are about to insert or update also insert the data to new table, then you can just query from the new table without in query

Source :
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause
https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/09/22/cassandra-query-patterns-not-using-the-in-query-for-multiple-partitions/

Comment: Thanks for your explain, big help!

Comment: The Approach 1 doesn't work because the id is string not int, but Approach 2 is a good point.

Answer (score 6):

My preferred way to issue these kind of queries is to *unroll* the `IN` part. That simply means you need to issue multiple queries in parallel, simply because the *token-o-matic* (aka token-aware) driver will treat each query as a single independent query, and will then spread these among different nodes, making each single node the coordinator responsible for each query it will be reached for.

You should run at most **X** queries and wait until at least one of them finishes (I use Java):

```
final int X = 1000;
ArrayList<ResultSetFuture> futures = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ResultSet> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < allTheRowsINeedToFetch; i++) {
    futures.add(session.executeAsync(myBeautifulPreparedStatement.bind(xxx,yyy,zzz)));
    while (futures.size() >= X || (futures.size() > 0 && futures.get(0).isDone())) {
        ResultSetFuture rsf = futures.remove(0);
        results.add(rsf.getUninterruptibly());
    }
}

while (futures.size() > 0) {
    ResultSetFuture rsf = futures.remove(0);
    results.add(rsf.getUninterruptibly());
}

// Now use the results
```

This is known as *backpressure*, and it is used to *move* the pressure from the cluster to the *client*.

The nice thing about this method is that you can go truly parallel (**X = allTheRowsINeedToFetch**), as well as truly serial (**X = 1**), and everything in between depends only *your* cluster hardware. Low values of **X** mean you are not using your cluster capabilities *enough*, high values mean you're going to call for troubles because you'll start to see timeouts. So, you really need to tune it.

Comment: In this code, X is the maximum concurrency, but the code won't ensure that we do have X in-flight requests. For example, if we have 1000 requests, X=10, the first request takes 1 second, all other requests take 1 ms each, then it will spawn 10 requests, and then wait ~1 second for the first request to finish, even though the remaining 9 "slots" are already available.

Comment: Sure, but I see this unlikely and as a non-problem: if the first query (or the 7th becoming the first) takes 1s then something is happening on your cluster, so pausing a bit seems the best thing to do IMHO. In addition, optimizing for the “true” parallel makes the code (much?) more complex. It doesn’t worth it…