# Efficient way to write asynchronously into cassandra using datastax java driver?

Tags: java, multithreading, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I am using datastax java driver 3.1.0 to connect to cassandra cluster and my cassandra cluster version is 2.0.10. I am writing asynchronously with QUORUM consistency.

```
  public void save(final String process, final int clientid, final long deviceid) {
    String sql = "insert into storage (process, clientid, deviceid) values (?, ?, ?)";
    try {
      BoundStatement bs = CacheStatement.getInstance().getStatement(sql);
      bs.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM);
      bs.setString(0, process);
      bs.setInt(1, clientid);
      bs.setLong(2, deviceid);

      ResultSetFuture future = session.executeAsync(bs);
      Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<ResultSet>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ResultSet result) {
          logger.logInfo("successfully written");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
          logger.logError("error= ", t);
        }
      }, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      logger.logError("error= ", ex);
    }
  }
```

And below is my `CacheStatement` class:

```
public class CacheStatement {
  private static final Map<String, PreparedStatement> cache =
      new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  private static class Holder {
    private static final CacheStatement INSTANCE = new CacheStatement();
  }

  public static CacheStatement getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private CacheStatement() {}

  public BoundStatement getStatement(String cql) {
    Session session = CassUtils.getInstance().getSession();
    PreparedStatement ps = cache.get(cql);
    // no statement cached, create one and cache it now.
    if (ps == null) {
      synchronized (this) {
        ps = cache.get(cql);
        if (ps == null) {
          cache.put(cql, session.prepare(cql));
        }
      }
    }
    return ps.bind();
  }
}
```

My above `save` method will be called from multiple threads and I think `BoundStatement` is not thread safe. Btw `StatementCache` class is thread safe as shown above.

- Since `BoundStatement` is not thread safe. Will there be any problem in my above code if I write asynchronously from multiple threads?
- And secondly, I am using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)` in the `addCallback` parameter. Is this ok or there will be any problem? Or should I use `MoreExecutors.directExecutor`. What is the difference between these two then? And what is the best way for this?

Below is my connection setting to connect to cassandra using datastax java driver:

```
Builder builder = Cluster.builder();
    cluster =
        builder
            .addContactPoints(servers.toArray(new String[servers.size()]))
            .withRetryPolicy(new LoggingRetryPolicy(DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy.INSTANCE))
            .withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)
            .withReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(100L))
            .withLoadBalancingPolicy(
                DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy
                    .builder()
                    .withLocalDc(
                        !TestUtils.isProd() ? "DC2" : TestUtils.getCurrentLocation()
                            .get().name().toLowerCase()).withUsedHostsPerRemoteDc(3).build())
            .withCredentials(username, password).build();
```

Comment: your creating a new thread pool every time save is called, instead make a static or instance version of the thread pool and reuse it.

Comment: Yeah I did that after reading below answer. I have declared it as final at the top of the class and then using it.. In general what is the difference between `MoreExecutors.directExecutor()` vs `threadpool`?

Comment: @ChrisLohfink Is there any real benefit of using `MoreExecutors.directExecutor()` vs `threadpool` in the callback? Can you help me understand this?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're doing is fine. You could optimize a bit further by preparing all the statements at application startup, so you have everything already cached, so you don't get any performance hit for preparing statement when "saving", and you don't lock anything in your workflow.

`BoundStatement` is not threadsafe, but `PreparedStatement` yes, and you are returning a new `BoundStatement` every time you call your `getStatement`. Indeed, the `.bind()` function of the `PreparedStatement` is actually a shortcut for `new BoundStatement(ps).bind()`. And you are not accessing the *same* `BoundStatement` from multiple thread. So your code is fine.

For thread pool, instead, you are actually creating a new thread pool on each `addCallback` function. This is a waste of resources. I don't use this callback method and I prefer managing plain `FutureResultSet` by myself, but I saw [examples](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/java-driver-async-queries) on datastax documentation that use `MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()` instead of `MoreExecutors.directExecutor()`.

Comment: Yeah I read that article only before coding this async stuff.. `sameThreadExecutor` is deprecated for `directExecutor` and that's why I asked about `directExecutor`... What is the best way and what do you recommend here for thread pool stuff then?

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40794021/6570821) to grasp the idea.