# Batch operation for select queries

Tags: scala, jdbc

I am having a million SELECT queries like

```
select id from accountTable where lastname ='' and firstName='' and zip='';
```

and will be using the PreparedStatement for that.

I know for batch I can use only insert/update/delete and never seen batches used for select statements.

In order to improve the performance, I want to execute it in the batch of 1000, may I know how can I do that in scala?

Comment: [You can't run JDBC batch statements for selects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899543/can-preparedstatement-addbatch-be-used-for-select-queries). So in your case, the only way to go is to create *bigger* queries. Maybe you could create big UNION query?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40790427/how-to-batch-select-data-from-cassandra-effectively

Comment: Can you share a little bit more of your code? How do you run your queries now?

Comment: If it's about processing several rows at a time, have you considered something like  a library with support for streaming and then running things in a stream? Like e.g. slick + akka stream + alpakka slick (integration between the two), or doobie + fs2?